# Get the Weight Of an object from the Weigh Machine(USB - Serial Port) in Java,Jsp

Tags: java, jsp, serial-port

How to Get the weight from serial port and I wanna set that weight in a table cell in jsp!! Please suggest me some tips to finish out this task.

I am Clear that serial Port program can be executed in Java Main method to get the weight, but how to set that weight in a Jsp component?

This [link](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=11) helped me to get the weight in serial port

I am getting the weight in Stream mode, But I wanna read the output in Manual or Command Mode.In hyperterminal, when I Click on the button manually only after that it reads the weight from machine!!

Where Should I do changes in java coding [Link](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=11) to read the weight after clicking any buttons as per the spec of weigh machine???

Comment: Help me out folks! Thank you in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Is that an external device you are talking about?  You must have some programming manual, at least a native one, and drivers to use it.  Then you can call your native program from java by using JNI

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/